# Search around values in std::vector

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 0,48000 };
e1 = left(v1,0); // should return first item's iterator
e1 = left(v1,10000); // should return first item's iterator
e1 = left(v1,20000); // should return first item's iterator
e1 = left(v1,48000); // should return the second item's iterator

e1 = right(v1,0); // should return first
e1 = right(v1,10000); // should return second
e1 = right(v1,48000); // should return second
e1 = right(v1,60000); // should return end()
```

My problem is how to implement functions `left` and `right`. std::upper_bound and std::lower_bound don't seem to help:

```
auto l1 = std::lower_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0); // 0
l1 = std::lower_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 14000); // 48000
l1 = std::lower_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 38000);
l1 = std::lower_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 48000);
l1 = std::lower_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 58000); // end()

auto l1 = std::upper_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 0); // 48000
l1 = std::upper_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 14000); // 48000
l1 = std::upper_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 38000); // 48000
l1 = std::upper_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 48000); // end()
l1 = std::upper_bound(v1.begin(), v1.end(), 58000); // end()
```

Basically, in a container which contains some sorted values, I want, by specifying an value that does not exist in the container, to take what's left and what's right on it (without of course searching manually in a loop if possible).

Comment: What should `left(-1)` return?

Comment: Some error, throw or even end().

Comment: And what, mathematically do you mean by “what’s left and right on it”?

Comment: It sounds like you have your first clue, then: there’s no idiomatic concept of “before the beginning” iterators. So consider what happens if you look at the predecessor of the return value of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

Comment: @Sneftel, the first less and the first greated value.

Comment: That doesn’t fit your examples of what happens if you pass in a value which is present in the array. 0 is not less than 0.

Comment: My  question states what happens when I pass a value that is *not* present in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your `right()` function finds an iterator pointing to the first element greater than or equal to a given value while the `left()` function returns an iterator pointing to the first element lesser than or equal to a given value.

So, your `right()` function should use `std::lower_bound()` while your `left()` function should do the same but with a greater-than comparator and with reverse iterators.

Try the following:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator left(std::vector<T> const& v, T const& val) {
    return v.empty() || val < v.front() || val > v.back()
        ? v.end()
        : std::next(std::lower_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), val, std::greater<T>())).base();
}

template <typename T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator right(std::vector<T> const& v, T const& val) {
    return v.empty() || val < v.front()
        ? v.end()
        : std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), val);
}
```